# Terminal in Intellij not working properly

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

Hi when I use IDEA to do a springboot project on the mac when I open the terminal in IDEA it shows nothing, and the below are my terminal settings in IDEA, anyone can help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0FIn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRMTR.png)

Comment: Do you mean that there is no cursor in terminal?

Comment: No, when I see people who can use the terminal properly, there is a a path when open a new window but I don't have that.

Comment: There is "Start directory" field on the second screenshot where you could set directory. Doesn't it work?

Comment: I already set that and it still doesn't work

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.